# Solving two-electron integrals

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I have been trying to teach myself Quantum Chemistry through a book, and I came across this problem and I am not sure how they solve a certain problem.

Essentially, they applied first-order perturbation theory to helium to get a correction term of $\frac{5}{8}Z$ by solving the equation given below in the question which I believe is the Coulomb integral between the two electrons in the $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital of Helium.

[image]

The next part of the question is what confuses me. They convert to spherical coordinates and the integral becomes much different.

[image]

At this point, I can solve the rest of the problem, but I am stuck on how the conversion worked, and I was wondering if anyone could help me.

Another question I have is that when solving for the electron-electron repulsion energy, would the conversion between the first integral expression to the second be the same if the electrons were in a separate orbital (i.e. For lithium between $\mathrm{1s}$ and $\mathrm{2s}$ electrons)?

Comment: I feel like this has been asked and answered [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integrals) not very long ago.

Comment: @user1271772 can you point to a more direct source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To introduce a $\theta$-dependency into the expression for $r_{12}$, use that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=ab \cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors:
$$r_{12}=|\vec{r}_{12}|=|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|=\sqrt{(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)^2}=\sqrt{\vec{r}_1^2-\vec{r}_2^2-2\vec{r}_1\cdot \vec{r}_2}=\sqrt{\vec{r}_1^2-\vec{r}_2^2-2r_1 r_2\cos \theta}$$
with $\theta=\theta_1=\theta_2$.

Now switch to a spherical coordinate system. The integral over the full 3d-space changes as follows:

$$\int\limits_\mathbb{R^3} \text{d}\vec{r}_2 = \int\limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d}r_2\int\limits_0^{\pi} \mathrm{d}\theta_2\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi_2\,r_2^2 \sin\theta_2$$
where $r^2 \sin\theta$ is the value of the Jacobian determinant of the transformation between spherical coordinates and Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It's the law of cosines. 1/norm(r1-r2) where both are vectors is the square root of (r1-r2)^2 = r1^2+r2^2-2(r1 dot r2)
The last term is the product of the norms times the cosine of the angle between them.
P.s. sorry I don't know how to format code. First time answering

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: I understood it was the rule of cosines that was used. I was more confused about how some of the added terms arose with the conversion to spherical coordinates like the integral with phi and also the $sin\theta d\theta$ term. I think I figured it out a few months back but I sort of forgot how it worked.